# Constant $k_g$ Loops and their lengths on constant $K$ surfaces _ The Loop Conjecture

Tags: differential-geometry

How does one prove that:

*Constant geodesic curvature lines drawn on constant Gauss curvature surfaces are closed loops.*

How do we find loop length $L$in terms of non-zero scalars $k_g,K ?$

EDIT1:

One such surface is given but is numerically computed.

EDIT2:

Basis of posting is my belief that for such smooth continuous loops even including the Area enclosed, all of four quantities below are isometric invariants connected by the Gauss-Bonnet theorem:

$$ \boxed{  K \cdot Area + k_g \cdot L = 2 \pi} $$

Is there a way to solve for $ L, Area $ bringing in *one more condition*? By using *geodesic polar coordinates* perhaps?

EDIT3:

A second case with orthographic projections is given below.
[image: kg const K const]
EDIT4:

I had posted earlier also on the topic about what essentially is my Conjecture.

Please help prove or disprove the Conjecture stated in second line italics above.

Comment: This is certainly false in the hyperbolic case, either in the hyperbolic plane or in the pseudosphere.

Comment: Can this be proved?

Comment: In the case of the hyperbolic plane, see section 3.2 (example and exercises) of my differential geometry notes in my profile.

Comment: I have not considered the hyperbolic plane. Both varieties (hypo, hyper) of pseudosphere with arbitrary boundary conditions gave me closed loops,

Comment: @Ted Shifrin May I request you to add in an answer how this Conjecture is certainly false.

Comment: Lines of constant geodesic curvature in the hyperbolic plane are full circles. The circle contains four cardinal points (two tangential and two normal) of intersection with three vertical $y$ lines. Imho this is adequate proof that the required lines have to be closed loops/ ovals.

Comment: No, that's true only for $k_g>1$. For $k_g\le 1$, the curves go to infinity, The case of $k_g=1$ is the case of horocycles.

Comment: For $ k_g≤1$ case  the loop cuts the cuspidal equator...we are in some agreement there.

Comment: "Some agreement"? Those cases invalidate your conjecture.

Comment: Thanks for discussion.There a clearer view now, and still working on it.. The governing ODE of the needed curve contains circular trig function that forces a closed loop formation. Also numerical work verifies it as above.