# Constant K negative non-orientable surface

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

What is a parametric co-ordinate representation of a (non-orientable) Möbius strip of constant negative Gauss curvature in $ \mathbb R^ 3.$

As per [MB_wiki](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusStrip.html)

$$ (x,y,z) = ( R+s \cos(t/2))  \cos t  \,,(R+ s \cos(t/2) )\sin t  \,,
 s \sin(t/2) ) $$

The standard parametrization above gives variable but negative $K$ per Equation (12). Some parametric re-adjustment could impart to it a constant negative K, or so I believe.As far my thoughts on the problem go I could not succeed in setting up a valid parametrization keeping half angle trig relations intact. In two rotations the point should come back periodic. Other trial and errors did not succeed.. there ought to be a stronger approach. If I hit one in the meantime shall post it here.

Any one typical or at least one parametrization isometric to $K=-1/R^2$ is requested, as I am unable to find even one such example in references anywhere. I checked Struik, Guggenheimer, the French 3dcurves site &c.

If possible please indicate a link that discusses any such possibilities.  If there is an indication why the question does not make full sense, that is also enough guidance at the moment..

Thanking in advance,

Regards

Comment: I'm not sure such a thing exists.  With constant positive curvature geodesics will naturally be closed.  With constant negative curvature we have saddle-like surface and a geodesic need not be closed.

Comment: Is there any such theorem?

Comment: I think a little reflection on the genus $0$ cases will convince you of the gist of what I wrote about geodesics.  Are you asking about "any such theorem" regarding that, or about a deeper idea?

Comment: I had numerically computed geodesics on either  sign of $K$ that are endless, but for certain relationship of constants in special case for periodic cases.Iirc there is a Pergamon monograph on the topic.. however am on mover​/holiday can get back later

Comment: Perhaps you should add the parameterization (or a link to it) to your Question.  A Möbius strip is a manifold with boundary, and it is non-orientable.  I'm not sure how a constant curvature $K$ appears in your parameterization.

Comment: I see that you asked [this related Question about closed loops](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891495/constant-k-g-loops-and-their-lengths-on-constant-k-surfaces-the-loop-conje) some time ago.

Comment: They are not un-orientable.